# Javascript query string error '=' comes out as %26

Tags: javascript

Any idea why this query string comes out like the one below?

```
var requestData = $('#txtCity').val() + ',' + $('#txtCountry').val() + '&APPID=e142d6277e3108bf30a12ab09c98ce6f';

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London%2CUK%26APPID%3De142d6277e3108bf30a12ab09c98ce6f
```

where txtCity is London and txtCountry is UK?

Comment: becasue it is url encoded

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182356/what-is-2c-in-an-url

Comment: The & is what's coming out as %26 and it's because you're url encoding it

Comment: What I feel is googling your issue beforehand is easier then posting it on Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [URL Encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Certain characters will be encoded/escaped to a % followed by 2 hex characters as these have special meaning in a URL string. The following can be found in your string

```
%2C is a comma (,)
%26 is an ampersand (&)
%3D is an equal sign (=)
```

Comment: How do I prevent this from happening

Comment: why do you want to prevent it? you could decode it using `decodeURI` method