# Using Python request.get param but it gives me wrong url

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to use Python request library to scrap some data from Steam. But first I need to modify my URL

for example, if I want to access games with tags

- 2D      [id : 3871]
- 1980s   [id : 7743]

https://store.steampowered.com/search?tags=7743%2C3871

this is the link I need. But when I do this

```
steam_url = "https://store.steampowered.com/search?"
search = request.get(steam_url, params = {'tags' : [7743, 3871]})
```

I get this URL

https://store.steampowered.com/search?tags=7743&tags=3871

which is showing me only 2D games [id : 3871]

To solve this I tried to do this

```
steam_url = "https://store.steampowered.com/search?"
search = get(steam_url, params = {'tags' : '%2C'.join(list(map(str,[7743, 3871])))})
```

Then I get this URL

https://store.steampowered.com/search?tags=7743%252C3871

I couldn't understand why there is **%252C** between those ids.

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is %2C in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182356/what-is-2c-in-a-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%2C` is the URL Encoded [hexadecimal value](http://www.asciitable.com/) of `,`. When you throw in `%2C` manually, the `request` package will try to make the actual value `%2C` safely URL-encoded, which will result into `%252C` (more specifically it will try to convert `%` into `%25`).

You're trying to url encode values, but so is the `request` package, which means that it's double encoded.

If you just write the `,` manually in the function it should work.

```py
steam_url = "https://store.steampowered.com/search?"
search = get(steam_url, params = {'tags' : ','.join(list(map(str,[7743, 3871])))})
```

However, just as [Hassan Voyeau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52578874/10400050) says, you don't need to make the function so complicated, you can just write the values normally by `{'tags': '7743,3871'}`, as long as you don't try to URL-encode any values manually.

Comment: Exactly. I wondered why my code was downvoted. I actually tested it and know it works.

Comment: Same with my answer, I tried to explain why it happens and how to avoid confusion in the future. Yours solves the problem more elegantly because it's not as much unnecessary code.

Comment: If I'm gonna get downvoted without any explanation for correctly answering a question and how to solve it I'll rather just delete my answer alltogether instead of helping.

Comment: thanks to you both, those comments really enlightened me. this problem was a huge setback for me, so thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you @ShayzeOn1. Please consider marking the answer that helped you the most, as solution for your question (assuming your problem got resolved).

Comment: If there is no explanatory comment, and you're confident that your answer is good then don't mind the negative votes. Some people may downvote just because they can, with no particular reason. +1 form me to cheer you up :)

Comment: Thanks @t.m.adam, it was childish of me, was in a bad mood already. Thanks for the positivity and the +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

> I couldn't understand why there is %252C between those ids.

Because you are using `'%2C'.join` which gets escaped as `%252C` with `%25` being the percent sign. Use `','.join` and let `requests.get` do the escaping.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. My testing of my code gives https://store.steampowered.com/search?tags=7743%2C3871

```
import requests

steam_url = "https://store.steampowered.com/search?"
search = requests.get(steam_url, params = {'tags' : '7743,3871'})

print(search.url)
```