# Huawei email cut link after comma

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

App Huawei Email cut link after comma that I pass through Intent.

```
val intent = Intent().apply {
                action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                type = "text/plain"
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://vk.com/lists?items=521168,658994,647670,662246,611036,658363")
```

Someone can tell why this is happening and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens because links can't contain this character as plain in fact, properly formatted link should be [HTML encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) with ASCII

```
val encodedLink = URLEncoder.encode(
    "https://yourlinkwithcommas",
    java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()
)
```

in your case it will exchange every coma char `,` with `%2C` - html encoded value. now just put `encodedLink` as `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`. more info in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182356/what-is-2c-in-a-url)